# Is there any opensource game frameworks in browser?

Tags: javascript

I have been looking for and found any.

Comment: Not nearly specific enough.

Comment: Do you mean Javascript/HTML only, or do you count Flash, Java, Game Maker, and so on as in-browser?  Are you only interested in real-time games?  Are you interested in back-end frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

There are many, some of most famous:

http://gamequery.onaluf.org/

http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascript_gamelib/javascript_gamelib.shtm

http://www.effectgames.com/effect/

http://mccormick.cx/projects/jsGameSoup/

http://rocketpack.fi/engine/